# Стилизация по PEP8 в python

Tags: python-3.x

По PEP8 название фунции должны быть нижним регистром и отделяться нижним анрскором, но сама стандартная библиотека не соблюдает этого стандарта? также и относится к классам.

Comment: Примеры можете привести? Мне вспоминается только названия встроенных типов вроде list или tuple, которые не является обычными питон-классами, поэтому и написание названий не такое, как у классов.

Comment: Так что вам нужно, можно уточнить вопрос?

Comment: так ведь встроенные (tuple, type, list) все они определены как класс почему написание название не следует PEP8? так и методы у некоторых классов через camel case, так ведь не по PEP все)

Comment: Исторически сложилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встроенные типы не являются классами, подобными обычным пользовательским классам.

До версии питона 2.2 такие имена как list, tuple, int были просто функциями, поэтому и писались с маленькой буквы. В отличие от пользовательских классов, от встроенных типов нельзя было наследоваться. Были ещё небольшие отличия от обычных классов.

Начиная с версии 2.2 встроенные типы и пользовательские классы почти полностью уравняли в правах, но имена остались старыми, чтобы не ломать уже существующий код.

По поводу названий методов в PEP8 написано:

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
> prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
> compatibility
>
> mixedCase допускается только в тех случаях, когда это уже
> преобладающий стиль (например, threading.py), чтобы сохранить обратную
> совместимость

То есть так уже было до того, как PEP8 был написан, и, соответственно, опять-таки не стали ничего исправлять, чтобы не ломать уже существующий код.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я узнал то что хотел узнать, надо бы нормально история python почитать)))